# jQuery: Make identical div appear

Tags: jquery

Im in this scenario:
http://jsfiddle.net/HXGrY/

I want to be able to click my  with the id #add-cyan, and make the  with the id #todo-cyan appear. And alike with all the other.

Can someone help me with this?

I want these

```
<img src="img/cyan.png" width="45px" class="hidden" id="todo-cyan"/>
<img src="img/magenta.png" width="45px" class="hidden" id="todo-magenta"/>
<img src="img/yellow.png" width="45px" class="hidden" id="todo-yellow"/>
<img src="img/black.png" width="45px" class="hidden" id="todo-black"/>
```

To show/slideDown when a img below them is clicked:

```
<img src="img/cyan.png" width="60px" height="60px" id="add-cyan"/>
<img src="img/magenta.png" width="60px" id="add-magenta"/>
<img src="img/yellow.png" width="60px" id="add-yellow"/>
<img src="img/black.png" width="60px"  id="add-black"/>
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Allright, i apologise. But i had no idea of the [id^="add-"] for one.
I managed to make one button do it, but i easily saw it would be a large uneccersary code.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('[id^="add-"]').click(function(){
    $('#todo-' + this.id.replace('add-', '')).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Ideally you should be using classes to group your `add` elements, so you don't have to pull the `'[id^="add-"]'` stunt.

To elaborate, I am selecting all elements with IDs starting with `add-`:

```
$('[id^="add-"]')
```

then adding a click handler that removes the `hidden` class from all elements with the corresponding `todo` ID:

```
$('#todo-' + this.id.replace('add-', '')).removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It might seem very easy, but i have JUST started learning, so i appreciate your help.

Would you mind doing a short explanation of your script? that would help me rewrite it greatly :D

Comment: @MagnusKristoffersen That's OK. You should have a look at some tutorials on selectors, there's a lot of stuff about jQuery I'm still discovering. I've added an explanation.

Comment: I want to learn, badly! I do HTML, CSS and basic php well, but just started jQuery and JavaScript. I'm using Codeacademy :)

Answer (score 1):

[***Update***](http://jsfiddle.net/HXGrY/4/)

Actually, it isn't even necessary to define all of those images twice, if all you're trying to do is duplicate the clicked one. Just [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone) it.

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("img.add").click( function() {
        $("#todobar").empty().append( $(this).clone() );
    });
});​
```

CSS

```
.add {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Modified HTML

```
<div id="todobar">
</div>

<img src="img/cyan.png" class="add" alt="cyan"/>
<img src="img/magenta.png" class="add" alt="magenta"/>
<img src="img/yellow.png" class="add" alt="yellow"/>
<img src="img/black.png" class="add" alt="black"/>
```

---

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/HXGrY/3/)

Useful jQuery methods to research: [`.click()` method](http://api.jquery.com/click), [jQuery `.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data), [jQuery `.show()` method](http://api.jquery.com/show), [jQuery `.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle). The jQuery documentation is pretty amazing, and the methods are fairly intuitively named. Try and keep your HTML canonical: as of HTML5 there is a data- attribute for adding data to markup. Also take a look at the different kinds of [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors). I have used the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) below (`'.add'`) and the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (`'#todo-cyan'`).

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("img.add").click( function() {
        var col = $(this).data("color");
        $("#todo-" + col).toggle();
    });
});​
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
    width: 45px;
}

.add {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Modified HTML

```
<div id="todobar">
    <img src="img/cyan.png" class="hidden" id="todo-cyan"/>
    <img src="img/magenta.png" class="hidden" id="todo-magenta"/>
    <img src="img/yellow.png" class="hidden" id="todo-yellow"/>
    <img src="img/black.png" class="hidden" id="todo-black"/>
</div>

<img src="img/cyan.png" class="add" data-color="cyan" alt="cyan"/>
<img src="img/magenta.png" class="add" data-color="magenta" alt="magenta"/>
<img src="img/yellow.png" class="add" data-color="yellow" alt="yellow"/>
<img src="img/black.png" class="add" data-color="black" alt="black"/>
```

Comment: @magnus No problem! Actually, I just added an even shorter way to do it :)

Comment: Hey man, i also have another set, with the data data-paper="a3-90", how do i implement this?

Comment: I should say i am using the first method, since it toggles!